# Inistiating A Class From A JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, jcombobox

I've begun learning some JFrame building and such and my problem is: How do I initiate a class from a JComboBox selection when I click a "start" button?

My packaging is:

- Scripts

  - Test

    - src

      - quests

        - Script1.java
      - Test.java

  Sorry if that seems confusing with the ordering, I can write it out if needed.

Anyways, I'd like to select a option from my JComboBox and when I hit "start", it will start the selected class from the quests folder... But how? Is this possible?

```
JButton button = new JButton("Start");
button.addActionListener(event -> {
    questName = questBox.getSelectedItem();
    log("Selected Quest: " + questName);
    frame.dispose();


    synchronized(Test.class) {
        Test.class.notify();
    }
```

Comment: `Class#forName`?  `Class#newInstance`?  Or maybe just `new Script1()`?

Comment: I managed to get this (sorry about the format):    `try {
    Class.forName((String) questName);
    log("trying to start: " + questName);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    log("failed to start: " + questName);
    e.printStackTrace();
   }` -- and in my log: "[INFO][Bot #1][08/18 10:25:25 PM]: failed to start: COOKS_ASSISTANT" -- Though I get no errors?

Comment: Make sure you pass the fully qualified name `quests.Script1`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, where would I put this?

Comment: In the Class#forName call

Comment: I tried but no luck.